# JavaScript Prototypical Inheritance - function not rendering proper alert

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am using prototypical Inheritance in JavaScript and trying to run a function on the prototype object:

***JS:***

```
//Constructor Function
var Person = function(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

//Adding custom function in Constructor
Person.prototype.speak = function(words){
    alert(this.name+" "+this.words)
}

//New Obj of Person as Prototype
var Tom = new Person('Tom','13');

//Printing variable Object
console.log(Tom);
Tom.speak("Hi");
```

***Expectation:***

```
1. I expected "Tom Hi" in alert 
2. speak function to be added into Obj as function
```

***Result:***

[image]
[image]

Can someone tell me why am I not getting expected alert AND why only name and age are coming as properties in Top and not "Speak"?

Comment: *“why only name and age are coming as properties in Top and not "Speak"?”* – You added `speak` to the Person *prototype*, so that’s where it will appear (second line from the bottom in your screenshot).

Comment: Note that variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors, so *tom* rather than *Tom*. ;-) Also, what you see in the console is very much implementation dependent. Most will allow you to see the internal `[[Prototype]]` property and you should find *speak* there ('cos that's where you added it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small mistake with your parameters. Here is how it is supposed to be:

```
Person.prototype.speak = function(words){
    alert(this.name + " " + words)
}
```

You were using `this.words` which is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining `this.words` anywhere, `words` is just an argument for `speak`. Use it as such:

```
alert(this.name + " " + words);
```

About the logging. Chrome console lists only the own properties of an object under the object itself. You can see prototype properties in properties of `__proto__`.